# Completely lost with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i have the following folder structure on my hosting (it is a shared one)

```
public_html
|
|
|--- website (contains CodeIgniter application)
|--- otherapp (another CodeIgniter application)
|--- moreapp (yet another web application)
```

What i want to do is that when ever a user type my domain (http://example.com) it should loads the content within the 'website' folder.

While a user type http://otherapp.example.com it should open what ever index.php reside within the 'otherapp' folder.

First i tried this (and saved it in the root folder[public_html]):

```
Redirect /index.php  http://example.com/otherapp/index.php and it pretty much screwed the URL and links.
```

Then i tried this (a brute copy paste from Joomla htaccess):

```
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks



## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On


# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]


##

# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL

# is not directly related to physical file paths.

# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]

# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Within otherapps folder (which is the codeigniter application i have this specific .htaccess)
which:
1. To get rid of index.php ending trail
2. Speed up web page load by doing some caching

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 


# 
# associate .js with "text/javascript" type (if not present in mime.conf)
# 
AddType text/javascript .js

# 
# configure mod_expires
# 
# URL: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html
# 
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

# 
# configure mod_headers
# 
# URL: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html
# 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
         Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 May 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
```

The problem that i am facing at the moment is that some links are not redirected properly. I am not sure how to explain the problem (i think it is too random).

Comment: Do you have access to Apache server config?

Comment: @anubhava No i dont, its on shared hosting. The only access i have is the public_html folder

Comment: So you want to show `http://domain.com/` or fine with showing `http://domain.com/website` also?

Comment: @anubhava i need to show http://domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!website/).*)$ website/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherapp\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!otherapp/).*)$ otherapp/$1 [NC,L]
```